# SQL Mangement Studio Cannot show requested Dialog

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2005-express

When using Server Management in SQL Server 2005 Express with Visual Studio 2010, I get the following error when attempting to add a database:

[image: SQL Error]

What could be causing this?  I already verified that the service is running...etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was chasing another error. I ended up using the information found below! Hope this helps another poor IT admin soul!

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/11/04/sql-server-fix-error-4064-cannot-open-user-default-database-login-failed-login-failed-for-user/

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue and find out that the dbowner is NULL(empty). After researching, I came across this script and after using it I was able to mview the db properties and fix the issue using the following query to find out the owner of each database through a T-SQL script:

```
SELECT name,
       suser_sname(owner_sid) AS owner,
       state_desc
FROM   sys.databases
```

For a SQL Server 2000 instance, you can use this:

```
SELECT name,
       suser_sname(sid)
FROM   sysdatabases
```

This revealed NULLs for a couple of databases in the instance, so I set the owner to SA using the following:
USE Northwind
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'

…tried accessing the properties through SSMS again and it worked like a charm